# delete a node in the middle of a single linked list, given only access to that node

Tags: c++

This is an interview question in "Cracking the coding interview". My code and test cases are here:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int data;
    node* next;
};
node* init(int a[], int n);
void remove(node* & c);
void printList(node* head);

int main()
{
    int a[]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    node* testHead=init(a, 10);
    printList(testHead);
    cout<<endl;
    int nth=9;
    node *c=testHead;
    for(int i=0; i<nth; i++)
    {
        c=c->next;
    }
    remove(c);
    printList(testHead);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

node* init(int a[], int n)
{
    node *head, *p;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        node *nd=new node();
        nd->data=a[i];
        if(i==0)
        {
            head=nd;
            p=nd;
        }
        else
        {
            p->next=nd;
            p=nd;
        }
    }
    return head;
}

void remove(node* & c)
{
    if(c==NULL)
        return;
    node* tmp=c->next;
    if(tmp==NULL)
    {
        delete c;
        c=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        c->data=tmp->data;
        c->next=tmp->next;
        delete tmp;
    }
}

void printList(node* head)
{
    while(head!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<head->data<<" ";
        head=head->next;
    }
}
```

Here in the main function, I tried to delete the last node, with the data value 9. 
However, even in the function "remove", I checked the last node and if it is, I set it to NULL, the output will produce an error.
Can anyone tell me why this happen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problems are actually as follows:

1. You should make the last node of list point to NULL while building the list.
2. When you delete the last node in the linked list, **the previous node -> next becomes a dangling pointer. This pointer has to be made to point to NULL**. Since you do not have its address, you will again have to traverse this list from the head node till you get the address of the node prior to the node to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

```
void remove(node* & c) // --> 1
{
    if(c==NULL)
       return;
    node* tmp=c->next;
    if(tmp==NULL)
    {
        delete c; // --> 2
        c=NULL; // --> 3
    }
    else
    {
        c->data=tmp->data;
        c->next=tmp->next;
        delete tmp;
    }
}
```

This is the thing:

1. When you pass in as a pointer, you does not necessary to pass in as a reference. It is redundant. `//Check @WhozCraig comment for correction`
2. `delete` releases `c` allocated memory
3. Therefore, you cannot assign a `NULL` to `c`

Other word, how can you assign `NULL` to a variable that has been released?

Comment: You may consider how powerful using a reference-to-pointer is in a correct algorithm if the referenced pointer is the `next` pointer from the prior node or `head` pointer in the case of the first node. It makes the removal absolutely trivial since you don't need to maintain a pointer to the node that holds the pointer to the victim.